# Enabling apache headers_module in.htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

Am buyildiung an angular2 application and hosted the php backend on a shared hosting. 
Whenever i send a post request am getting an error of

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

In my local xampp i had to enable headers_module in the apache to resolve this, Ive contacted the shared hosting company but they cant enable the module

How can i go around this probably in the .htaccess file

This is current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

 # hide files and folders
 RedirectMatch 404 /_protected
  RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
 RedirectMatch 404 /composer\.
 RedirectMatch 404 /.bowerrc

 # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

What do i need to add in the above .htaccess file to act as a go around for this error, or even as a bypass for the

```
headers_module
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `.htaccess` to load a module. The [LoadModule  directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) context is:

```
server config, virtual host
```

But you don't need to rely on the server configuration, PHP can generate HTTP headers just fine:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

([reference](http://php.net/header))

Of course, Yii has a [builtin mechanism to generate HTTP headers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#http-headers).

Comment: Ive also set the headers in yii2 but still the error is returned,  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource